# Unhandled async exception

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Reasons for avoiding `async void` aside, is it possible to catch the following error from calling code?

```cs
private static Action ErrorAction
{
  get
  {
    return async () =>
    {
      await Task.Delay(0);
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    };
  }
}
```

For example in both of the following I'd like to collect the exceptions thrown, but both tests fail:

```
[Test]
public void SelfContainedExampleTryCatch()
{
  List<Exception> errors = new List<Exception>();
  try
  {
     ErrorAction();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    errors.Add(ex);
  }
  errors.Count().Should().Be(1);
}

[Test]
public void SelfContainedExampleContinueWith()
{
  List<Exception> errors = new List<Exception>();
  var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(ErrorAction);
  task.ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    errors.Add(t.Exception);
                }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
  task.Wait();

  errors.Count().Should().Be(1);
}
```

I know I could use a method with an `async Task` signature; but specifically it's the Action assignable delegate async code sample I'm needing to handle, and catching at a global level isn't practicable. If it's possible, a solution common for both sync and async Actions would be ideal.

Hopefully there's a simple solution I've missed, but so far I've only headed down numerous dead ends and have (perhaps incorrectly) concluded it's not possible. Any help (or time-wasting saved) would be appreciated!

Comment: At what point do the tests fail?

Comment: The error is unhandled - it doesn't add to the `errors` list.

Comment: So you're saying the test fails with an unhandled exception at the `ErrorAction();` line?

Comment: If you run in debug then you get an unhandled error dialog - then the test continues and fails on the last line. If you run without debug the test just fails at the last line. DebuggerNonUserCode's not the issue, the problem's that the error's unhandled.

Comment: @mason The tests will fail on the assert `errors.Count().Should().Be(1);` because the exceptions won't be propagated.

Comment: @lonewolf, exactly. Is it at all possible to cause them to "propagate"?

Comment: I find that if I introduce async code into my inner handler, I have to make the calling code async, and the calling code of THAT async. It ends up being async-all-the-way-down. Can you explain WHY you can't use a method with the `async Task` signature?

Comment: @9swampy No, I can't think of any way. Does ErrorAction need to return an Action? Can't you just return a Task?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd It doesn't have to be async all the way up. You can at run an async command via `var task = MyCallAsync(); task.Wait();` from a method that is not marked as async.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd &Lonewolf - changing would break an existing contract; which I'm loathe to do but seemingly I'm going to have to...

Comment: @mason code with `.Wait` will deadlock in most .Net frameworks (WinForms, WPF, ASP.Net), but indeed it is an approach.

Answer (score 2):

There are some cases where a framework requires you to use `async void` when sometimes you'd really rather not (e.g., `ICommand.Execute`). In these cases, I generally recommend introducing an `await`-compatible API and just make your `async void` methods very simple wrappers:

```
static Func<Task> ErrorActionAsync
{
  get
  {
    return async () =>
    {
      await Task.Yield();
      throw new NotImplementedException();
    };
  }
}

private static Action ErrorAction
{
  get
  {
    return async () => { await ErrorActionAsync(); }
  }
}
```

(on a side note, I changed `await Task.Delay(0)` to `await Task.Yield()` since `await Task.Delay(0)` is a noop).

Then you can use `ErrorActionAsync` rather than `ErrorAction` in your unit tests. This approach does mean you'll have small amounts of untested code (the `async void` wrapper - `ErrorAction`).

However, if you want to keep `ErrorAction` as-is, and it can be synchronous *or* asynchronous, then there is another possibility. I have written an [`AsyncContext` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) that you can use like this:

```
[Test]
public void SelfContainedExampleTryCatch()
{
  List<Exception> errors = new List<Exception>();
  try
  {
    AsyncContext.Run(() => ErrorAction());
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    errors.Add(ex);
  }
  errors.Count().Should().Be(1);
}
```

`AsyncContext.Run` will block until the `async void` method completes, and will capture exceptions from `async void` methods and raise them directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want ErrorAction to be able to cater for asynchronous calls and then still be able to handle exceptions at the call site, then I think you will just have to bite the bullet and change the ErrorAction to return `Task`.

If you do decide to change the contract, it will probably be a good idea to maintain the synchronous nature of your existing non-async implmentations. You can do this by:

```
private static Task ErrorAction
{
  get
  {
    // Synchronous code here

    return Task.FromResult(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think returning Task is possible without changing the contract. See this example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FluentAssertions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
    class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            SelfContainedExampleTryCatch();
            SelfContainedExampleContinueWith();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }

        public static void SelfContainedExampleTryCatch()
            {
            var errors = new List<Exception>();
            try
                {
                ErrorAction();
                }
            catch (Exception ex)
                {
                errors.Add(ex);
                }
            errors.Count().Should().Be(1);
            }

        public static void SelfContainedExampleContinueWith()
            {
            var errors = new List<Exception>();
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(ErrorAction);
            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                errors.Add(t.Exception);
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
            task.Wait();

            errors.Count().Should().Be(1);
            }

        private static Action ErrorAction
            {
            get
                {
                return () => DoTask().Wait();
                }
            }

        private static async Task DoTask() {
            await Task.Delay(0);
            throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
    }
```

The ContinueWith test passes, but the other test won't. Which I believe is your intention.

Comment: @lonewolf I believe there's no way around that. If you didn't want it to block, then you'd need to change the contract.

Comment: The problem is I've got an exposed contract that accepts an Action - I have no control over what the third party passes in so rearranging the input unless I can put something between the accepted action and the calling code won't work out, thanks for the suggestion nonetheless.